# No Way to Set Initial View Controller in New Storyboard in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode

Here's what I did in Xcode 6.0.1:

**Step 1:** Create a new project with a single view.

[image]

**Step 2:** Add an *additional* storyboard to the project.

[image]

**Step 3:** Compare the original storyboard with the newly added one. Note how there is *no arrow to designate the initial view controller*. I can't find a way to add one, either.

[image]
[image]

Is this expected behavior? Can you only have one initial view controller per application? I thought I could have one per storyboard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you look in the Attributes Inspector for the view controller, can you tick "is Initial View Controller"?

Comment: i can tick it and have 2 root views than.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Select the view controller, then use the “Is Initial View Controller” checkbox in the attributes inspector.

[image: initial view controller]

Comment: Not true in Xcode 6.2 anymore. Look at the answer below for 6.2.

Comment: will it also set that controller as rootViewController of mandatory property of UIWindow in AppDelegate?

Comment: @BaSha Yes. The initial view controller becomes the root view controller of the app delegate's window.

Comment: is there any shortcut key to set the initial view controller just to save time from going to utilities inspector than setting initial viewcontroller.

Answer (score 15):

In Xcode 6.2, there is no longer an "Is Initial View Controller" checkbox in the attributes inspector. Instead, you set the initial view controller by adding the Storyboard Entry Point found in the Object Library.

Comment: In Xcode 7, there is an “Is Initial View Controller” check box in the view controller's Attributes Inspector, and there is no entry point item in the Object Library.

Answer (score 4):

"Is initial View Controller" is back in XCode 6.3.x.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 6, use a "Storyboard Entry Point" from the object library.  Drag the control onto the View Controller you wish to designate as the initial View Controller.

Answer (score 0):

The Story Entry Point does not exist in Object Library in Xcode 6.x, and cannot upgrade to Xcode 6.3.x for now in china.

Comment: after upgraded to Xcode 6.3, the 'Is Initial View Controller' option is back. and i just found we could always drag the 'Entry Point' arrow to specify initial view controller.