# I am trying to build and launch my app with xcode 9.2 and when I build on a device it it is just a white screen

Tags: xcode, build

The screen is just white whenever I try and open my app on the device and the simulator. I have built and ran apps successfully before but I can't figure out why this one won't build correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things that could cause this, but the first thing I would check is to make sure the [initial view controller is set properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26224251/3047919).

Comment: I tried to do that but it was already the initial view controller. Is there anything else I could try?