# show the second ViewController when app launch the second time

Tags: swift, view, viewcontroller, launch

so when i launch my app the first time there is a welcome ViewController. How can i set a function, that shows the second ViewController  when the user launches the app the second time.

Comment: You are looking at this backwards. Your logic should be how to only show the welcome screen on the first launch. And that has been covered here many times.

Comment: okay can u say me how to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Boolean in the user default in your application to check whether the application is launch first time or not. Based on this Boolean value load another ViewController in your app delegate class.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
     let isFirst = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: “isLaunched”) // edited this after rmaddy's comment 
     var viewControllerWithIdentifier = "SecondViewController"
     if !isFirst {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: “isLaunched”)
        viewControllerWithIdentifier = "FirstViewController"
     }
     let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let initialViewController : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(viewControllerWithIdentifier) as UIViewController
     self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
     self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
     self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
     return true
}
```

Comment: the app still launches with the first viewcontroller

Comment: do i have to put this ```func```in the ```AppDelegate.swift```file ?

Comment: This logic isn't correct. The `isFirst` variable will always be true.

Comment: ive tried it with ```isFirst.toggle()```its still not working

Comment: @rmaddy how?  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: “isFirst”) will return false as its value will be set to false in the if condition. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @flolopi Yes you have to put the above code in AppDelegate file.  
 in your story board remove the arrow from your FirstViewController, or disable the "is Initial View Controller" from utility panel in story board when you have selected your FirstViewController.  for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224171/no-way-to-set-initial-view-controller-in-new-storyboard-in-xcode-6

Comment: Actually, I take back what I said. The code you posted won't even compile. `bool(forKey:)` doesn't return an optional. But even if it did, it's still wrong. The first time the app runs, there is nothing in UserDefaults. So `UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: “isFirst”)` returns `false` even though it is the first run.

Comment: @rmaddy yes you are right even noticed that few minutes ago. Sorry.

Comment: so i have to use several storyboards ? right now i have one Storyboard with three different viewcontroller

Comment: @flolopi no, no need of having several storyboards.  The Storyboard which you talking about is also known as "Main" which we are loading in the line let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

All you are going to do in the above code is loading Storyboard via code and specifying which ViewController needs to be loaded.

Comment: By "doesn't work" what do you mean? Is it crashing or not loading the 2nd view controller? try setting break points.

Comment: it is not loading the second viewcontroller

Comment: i have to replace the ```func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }```with the function of abdul right?

Comment: have you disabled the "is Initial View Controller" from Storyboard for your FirstViewController i.e. unchecked the "is Initial View Controller"?
If you did then try to set break point at 



     let initialViewController : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(viewControllerWithIdentifier) as UIViewController
and check the value of viewControllerWithIdentifier .

Comment: use menu entry Product->Debug->Add Breakpoint at Current line
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931959/how-do-you-add-a-breakpoint-in-xcode

Comment: there are several types of breakpoints. wich one should i take ?

Comment: i also get the warning   instance method 'application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)' of protocol 'UIApplicationDelegate'.   Make 'application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)' private to silence this warning

Comment: Use this func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool

Comment: yeah now it is working, but the secondViewController is instant shown. from the very first launch

Comment: Clear your simulator first, as you have already run the application earlier the user default have the value for “isLaunched”. So clearing your simulator will remove the user default. Or removing your application from simulator will also work. And also Use - “ if !isFirst{ “in the code